# Interval of stokes theorem

Tags: calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I have the vectorfield  $F=(y e^x,x^2+e^x,z^2)$
and the curve $r(t)=(1+cos(t),1+sin(t),1-cos(t)-sin(t))$

I have to find the line integral of this using stokes theorem, however in this case I'm only interested in the interval. And I'm confused about how to define the $r$ region interval.

When the curve is projected on the x-y plane it creates a circle with center in (1,1) and r=1. Here $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$. But how should I interpret $r$? Does the height of $y$ matter? because if it does not then the $r$ goes from 1 to 2 so that the interval becomes,

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{1}^{2} \,rdr d\theta$

But I'm confused if this is correct because I have only previously solved problems where the sphere had center in the origin. So do things change when the center moves away from the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to evaluate line integral over closed curve with $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ and with positive orientation.

If you are applying Stokes' theorem to evaluate the line integral, you can consider any surface with the given curve as its boundary. The easiest in this cases will be

$\phi(r, t) = (1 + r \cos(t), 1 + r \sin(t), 1 - r \cos(t) - r \sin(t))$
$0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

$ \vec n =  \phi_r \times \phi_t = (r - r \cos t, r - r \sin t, r)$

Also note, $\nabla \times \vec F = (0, 0, 2x) = (0, 0, 2 + 2 r \cos t)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: From what you provided, wouldn't it be

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} (0,0,2+2rcos(t))(r-rcos(t),r-rsin(t),r) \,rdr dt$

$=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r(2rcos(t)+2) \,rdr dt =\frac{4\pi}{3}$

But I'm confused about a few things.
When computing $\nabla \times \vec{F}$, how do $2x = 2+2rcos(t)$.

Also how can $r$ be $0≤r≤1$, when the center of the sphere is not in the origin?

Comment: @Zert44 let's resolve one thing at a time. First the integral has an extra $r$. When you find $\phi_r \times \phi_t$, it should not be multiplied by $r$ again. So the answer should be $2\pi$.

Comment: The integral is $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} (0,0,2+2rcos(t))(r-rcos(t),r-rsin(t),r) \, dr \,dt$

Comment: I think what is keep confusing me is that I think the integral should be converted to polar form because the x-y projection is a circle. so when I did the integral I initially went $rdrd\theta$ and realized it should be $drdt$ and forgot to remove r

Comment: that's ok. now coming to the next question... once you get $\nabla \times \vec F = (0, 0, 2x)$, use your parametrization of the surface to replace $x, y, z$.

Comment: From $ϕ(r,t)$ x would be $x = 1+rcos(t)$, but I still can not get it to make sense

Comment: yes so on the surface $2x = 2 (1 + r \cos t)$, right? or may be I am not understanding your question

Comment: right, I don't why this seems so hard for me to figure out right now

Comment: is your question how $\nabla \times \vec F = (0, 0, 2x)$?

Comment: No I calculated that myself also, and got the same. I understand this part now

Comment: ok next, the curve is an ellipse in 3D and not a circle. Now there are many surfaces that have the same boundary that you can use to apply Stokes' theorem but the easiest is to use a disk whose boundary is the given ellipse. Now the point to note that that the projection of this ellipse in xy-plane is a circle $(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$. When you use parametrization $x = 1 + \cos t, y = 1 + \sin t$, you are translating the origin of the coordinate system to $(1, 1)$ so, that makes it a circle centered at the origin in the new coordinate system. Hence $0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you very much for the help :)